# can't access elements inserted by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, insert, click

I made myself a little tag input field but i can't access the inserted tags with jquery.

Everytime you hit enter the value of the input field will be inserted before the input as a `<div class="chip"></div>`.

If i try to do something on click it's only working for tags that aren't inserted by the input.

```js
$('.chip').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});

$('.wrap input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var key = e.which,
      input = $(this),
      value = input.val();
 
  if(key === 13) {
    if(value != '') {
      $('<div class="chip">' + value + '</div>').insertBefore(input);
      $(input).val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrap .chip {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.wrap input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrap input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="chip">tag1</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.wrap').on('click', '.chip', function() {
  console.log('click');
});

$('.wrap input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var key = e.which,
      input = $(this),
      value = input.val();
 
  if(key === 13) {
    if(value != '') {
      $('<div class="chip">' + value + '</div>').insertBefore(input);
      $(input).val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrap .chip {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.wrap input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrap input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="chip">tag1</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

The events are only bound to the elements that are available in the `DOM`. To account for the newly inserted dom nodes, you will have to delegate the events to the ancestors which are available at the time of binding the events.

**Change**

```
$('.chip').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

**to**

```
$('body').on('click', '.chip', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

`body` can be replaced with the closest ancestor that is present in your DOM at the time of binding.